# UI router state that dispatches/forwards to other states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The entry point to our Angular application (e.g. after signing in), or when no other route is found (`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()`) should be a **UI router 'dispatch' state that decides to which state to forward to**, maybe based on some `resolves`. This dispatch state is a *leaf state*, so I do not want to solve the problem to jump to a child state from a parent state.

I see two ways where to put the redirection logic and the actual transition through `$state.go()`:

1. In the **`onEnter` function** of the dispatch state. This works when the dispatch state is the first state the user jumps to. If the application was loaded already and then the user jumps to the dispatch state, there is the following error on the console:

   `TypeError: Cannot read property 'globals' of null
   at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3231)
   at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3112)
   at Object.$stateProvider.state.state.onEnter (home.routes.js:62)
   at Object.invoke (angular.js:4523)
   at $state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (angular-ui-router.js:3322)
   at processQueue (angular.js:14792)
   at angular.js:14808
   at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052)
   at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15870)
   at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)`

   We use UI router 0.2.17. This is mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/326), which is closed.
   The advantage of this solution would be that the view of the dispatch is not loaded but redirection happens instantly.
2. In the **controller of the dispatch state**. In this case, the view of the dispatch state is loaded and the user would thus see a 'flickering' before he is forwarded to the target state.

**So how would we properly implement this 'dispatch state'? Is having a state like this a bad idea in general?**